# How to handle Customer Authentication that is, registration, login and reset password using shopify’s APIs

Tags: shopify

I am building an SPA (Single Page Application) with react for the customer portal of my store , using shopify’s admin APIs and bold commerce APIs.
I have most of it figured out asides for the authentication part, I want to be able to handle the normal authentication on the SPA so when a customer has finished shopping, he is asked to log into the SPA and the order will reflect there. The Major challenge is that, currently on the theme, for every checkout the customer must login in other to checkout, but I want this login to happen in my SPA and the checkout in the shopify theme. I am not sure if the architecture makes sense, but I am totally new  to this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot login with using Shopify authentication, with the exception that Plus offers Multipass login.

Comment: So how do you suggest we go about this architecture

Comment: I don't. Shopify authentication is not open for playing around, so I don't. I am surprised you did not research this before anything else.

Comment: I did have an email conversation with someone at bold, they asked us to build a SPA for the work we set out to achieve, and in other to do that we will need authentication, or do you suggest something different ?

Comment: Bold asked you to do work for them? Haha. Good for you! Best of luck in your endeavors.